# Find the maximum number of 4-passengers contiguous clusters

Tags: python, programming-challenge

**Problem Statement**

1. An airline wants to allocate seats in their aircrafts such that each group of four passengers travelling together are to be seated next to each other in clusters of 4. A contiguous cluster can have an isle running through it - for example, you can sit one passenger on one side of the isle, and three on the other side, as long as there are no passengers from other parties in that cluster. Clusters must be on the same row.
2. There are 10 seats in each row, arranged in a 2 - 6 - 2 pattern (i.e. 2 seats, then an isle, then 6 seats, then an isle, then two seats). Rows range from 1 .. 40 and seats from A - K, skipping I
3. You are given an integer number of rows (N) and a space-delimited string (S) representing occupied seats. For example, "1A 2A 3B 5C 40F" would indicate occupied seats in rows 1 - 40. Similarly, "1A 2A 3B 5C" would indicated occupied seats in rows 1 - 5.
4. You are required to write a function `seat(N,S)`, representing the number of rows and occupied seats respectively, and have to return the maximum number of 4-passenger contiguous clusters.

**Solution Approach**

1. Check for the trivial case of S = '' and N = 1 and return 2
2. Parse the occupied seats string into a list of strings using S.split(' ') to get individual seat allocation
3. Map the letters A - K into numbers 0 - 9
4. Create a 2D matrix map of seats
5. Parse the matrix row by row, looking for a patterns of 4 seats and return their count

**Code**

Fully documented code as follows:

```
import re

def printMatrix (M):

    print('\n'.join([''.join(['{:4}'.format(item) for item in row])
      for row in M]))

def sliceMatrix (M, C):
    counter = 0;
    clusters = 0;

# the approach here is to keep a count of where we checked last in the variable counter
# if we fail, we increment the counter by 1 and slice the next cluster of 4
# if we succeed in finding a cluster of 4 available seats, then we increment the number of
# clusters by 1 and the counter by 4.
# we then return the total number of clusters found in a row

    for i in range (counter, len(M)):
# loop over array taking a slice of 4 spaces from where the current counter is
        fourSlice = M[counter:counter+4];
        print(fourSlice)
# check for the number of 0s in that slice
        numZeros = fourSlice.count(0);
        print("numZeros: ", numZeros);
# success: there are 4 zeros, then this is a cluster
        if (numZeros == 4):
            print("Found cluster. Clusters now: ", clusters + 1)
# increment the number of clusters found by 1
            clusters += 1;
# move the counter 4 spaces
            counter += 4;
# skip the rest of the loop iteration
            continue;
# failure: increment the counter by 1 and loop
        else:
            counter += 1;
        print ("i: ", i, " counter: ", counter)
    print("total clusters found in this row: ", clusters)
# return the total number of clusters found in this row
    return (clusters);

def solution(N, S):

# a dictionary to map column labels to numbers.
# this is necessary to obtain numerical values for the 2D matrix seat map.  Is there a better way?
    columnDict  = {'A' : 0, 'B' : 1, 'C' : 2, 'D' : 3, 'E' : 4, 'F' : 5, 'G' : 6, 'H' : 7, 'J' : 8, 'K' : 9}

    # check the trivial case whereby only one empty row exists and return 2
    if (N == 1 and S==''):
        return 2;

    # construct an empty 2D matrix map of the aircraft seating of the format N x 10
    seatMap = [[0 for n in range(10)] for y in range(N)];

    # convert the occupied string list into a list of individual seat strings
    S = S.split(' ');

    # iterate over the array, and populate 2D map

    for seat in S:
# search for one or more digits, followed by a single letter, placing each in a group
# digits are row numbers, letters are seat labels
        m = re.search ("(\s*[\d]+)([abcdefghjkABCDEFGHJK]\s*)", seat)
        if m:
# grab the first group from the match object, representing row number
            occupiedRow = m.group(1);

# grab the second group from the match object, representing column label
            occupiedColumn = m.group(2);
# convert the row number into a matrix index by decrementing it by 1. this is to account for
# machine representation of indexes, which start at 0
            MR = int(occupiedRow) - 1;
# map the seat label to a number so that it can also be used as a matrix index.
# this is done as a dictionary lookup from the columnDict hash defined earlier
            MC = columnDict[occupiedColumn];
# now we have a [row][column] matrix number, populate that entry as occupied
            seatMap[MR][MC] = seat;
# just be helpful, and print the seat map
    printMatrix(seatMap);

# next, iterate over seat map row by row, and extract each row to a 1d array
# but first, we initialise a total cluster counter, to keep cumulative track
# of how many clusters we get from the seat map matrix
    totalClusters = 0;

    for i in range(N):
        # slice a row from the seat map into a 1d array
        rowSlice = seatMap[i][0:9]

        # pass that slice to the sliceMatrix function to get the number of clusters in that row
        numClusters = sliceMatrix(rowSlice, 4)

        # keep cumulative track of clusters we get
        totalClusters += numClusters;

        # return the total number of clusters found
    return (totalClusters)



# this is a sample occupancy string of an aircraft with 7 rows (N = 7)
S = "1A 1B 1F 2A 2B 2C 2D 3A 3C 3D 4A 4B 4E 5A";
N = 7;

Clusters = solution(N, S);

print ("Total Clusters: ", Clusters);
```

**Thoughts**

Could this be done any more efficiently or better/faster/...etc? Could the splitting of string S be done without regex, remembering that row numbers can be single or double digits?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Please read https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: In the title, you should state what your code does.  This is clearly stated in [ask].  You should [edit] the question to give it an appropriate title.  This will help in getting reviewers to look at your code.

Comment: Why can't I find a *function `seat(N,S)`*? Please edit into your problem statement: How is *maximum number of 4-passenger contiguous clusters* to be interpreted, especially *maximum*? If it is about allocated seats (if it was about free seats, it would read *4-seat clusters*, wouldn't it?), how do "5-seat clusters not part of a  6-seat cluster" count: two (overlapping) 4-seat clusters, one, or none?

Comment: Please properly attribute quoted contents if at all possible - you tagged this [tag:programming-challenge]. The conventional MarkDown is a block quote (`> ` line prefix/`"` in the *post editor* tool-bar).

Comment: OK,thanks for your stylistic comments everyone, appreciated.  Grateful if someone can actually look at the code and give tech feedback?

Comment: `["thanks", everyone]` have a look at some reviews with a score of at least two of code presented in questions with score at least one. Take a guess how much time you'd need to invest to present a review equally useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is *Code Review*@SE:

Do not start coding while not confident the task is well defined.

A good way to check is *test first*:
If you don't know how to test it, you don't know what to achieve.
(Your program (sort of) outputs

> ```
> 1A  1B   0   0   0  1F   0   0   0   0  
> 2A  2B  2C  2D   0   0   0   0   0   0  
> 3A   0  3C  3D   0   0   0   0   0   0  
> 4A  4B   0   0  4E   0   0   0   0   0  
> 5A   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  
>  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  
>  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
> ```

- how many clusters of 4 do you see? Your program: `Total Clusters:  9`)

Almost as helpful is to *somehow* record the approach envisioned (viability of updates and version handling as welcome as with code) -
**well done**, presenting it before going into detail.
I would have loved it if it was *in the code*.

Two things irritating about the problem statement:
 • no indication what is *maximum* about the *maximum number of clusters* to return
 • mention of *isles*, which seem to be dispensable

---

There are conventions, lowering the threshold to grasp someone else's work.
Many Python conventions a formalised as [Python Enhancement Proposals](https://www.python.org/dev/peps). I put first:

1. [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds)
   there is no *just about style*: it's *about* **readability**
2. [PEP 257 -- Docstring Conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring)
   "If you violate these conventions, the worst you'll get is some dirty looks."
   And *not the best software for the given effort*.
   I wish I found `Fully documented code`.

Going through the code top to bottom, *not* commenting deviations from PEP 8 (*Everyone* is using tool help) and referring to [Sam Stafford's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/236914/93149) regarding useful code comments:

- `printMatrix(M)`
  • flawless use of comprehensions.
  • Lacks a docstring -
   `Print the matrix using no less than four characters per item.`?
  • Unified alignment: `'{:<4}'.format(item)`
- `sliceMatrix(M, C)`
  • Not named for what it returns/computes/modifies.
  • Lacks a docstring -
   `Return the count of contiguous clusters of size C in M.`?
  • Features not only the magic literal `4`:
   what could(/should?) be (is?!) a parameter leaks into the name of a variable.
  • Contains "tracing-`print()`s" not easy to disable.
  • `i` used exclusively for trace printing
  • (Misses the opportunity to advance four seats when `num_zeros` is 0
   ***“Premature optimisation is the root of all evil*** (or at least most of it) **in programming.”**   - D.E. Knuth)
  • Keeps going when `n_columns < counter + cluster_size`
- `solution(N, S)`
  • Lacks a docstring -
   `Return the maximum number of 4-passenger contiguous clusters.`?
  • Is on the long side - consider factoring out *taking reservations into account* and *counting clusters*
  • An alternative to `columnDict[occupiedColumn]` is    `"ABCDEFGHJK".find(occupied_column)`
  • does not iterate seatMap "the pythonic way": `for row in seat_map:`
  • creates a slice without striking need

  - using explicit start and end instead of `row_slice = row[:]`

    - not using a symbolic upper bound: `row_slice = row[0:seats_per_row]`

      - using a literal of `9`, which is the last valid index and one less than a tolerable upper bound **leading to wrong (low) results** when there is a block of unoccupied seats "on the right" with a length divisible by 4
- `seat(N, S)`
  • Missing, but specified by the problem statement.
- put your "tinker test" after an
  `if __name__ == '__main__':` - if more than a couple of lines, better define a `main()`

---

There are many ways to reach a solution -

- start at the problem
- design and code the way *you* think about problem and solution
  giving others (including your later self (**!**)) a chance to follow your thinking:
  **Document your design.

  Document your code. In the code.**

---

My take of "the map approach", sans module docstring:

```
def seating(N, empty, S):
    ''' Return a seating of N rows initially <empty>,
     with taken seats from S blanked out. '''
    seats = [empty]*N
    for taken in S.split():
        row = int(taken[:-1]) - 1
        seats[row] = seats[row].replace(taken[-1], ' ', 1)

    return seats


def count_clusters(seating, cluster_size):
    ''' Return the count of contiguous cluster_size clusters in seating. '''
    return sum(len(cluster) // cluster_size for row in seating
               for cluster in row.split())


def seat(N, S):
    ''' Return the maximum number of 4-passenger contiguous clusters. '''
    return count_clusters(seating(N, "ABCDEFGHJK", S), cluster_size=4)
```

---

Sketch of an "interval approach":

- start with one interval per row
- for each reservation
  • split every interval at the seat specified
  • discard all short intervals
- count intervals

food for thought:
• ordering reservations (say, by ascending row) allows handling row by row 
• manipulating some form of "dance card" is equivalent to bucket sorting reservations

Comment: nice and simple. I do not like the reuse of the `seating` name in the `count_clusters` method, but for the rest this is very elegant.

Answer (score 3):

Two comments on your comments:

1. Have the comment be at the same indentation level as the block that you're commenting.  Having all the comments start at column 0 forces the eye to rapidly scan from left to right, and it makes it impossible to discern the overall structure of the program at a glance from the left-hand margin of the code.  (It looks like not all the code has this problem, but enough of it does to be very distracting.)
2. Comments should describe and rephrase the purpose of a block (a logical chunk) of code, not describe what each individual line of code does.  For example, this:

   ```
   # pass that slice to the sliceMatrix function to get the number of clusters in that row
   numClusters = sliceMatrix(rowSlice, 4)
   ```

is not a useful comment, because I can already see that you're calling the `sliceMatrix` function, I can see that you're passing `rowSlice` to it, and I can see that you're calling the result `numClusters`.

---

On the matter of how to parse a seat string, this is simple enough that you don't really need a regex or even the manually specified letter:number mapping.  The fact that the column is always expressed as a single letter makes it easy to do by slicing:

```
# Seats are specified as a row number followed by a column letter, e.g. "22D".
# Our seat map is zero-indexed so row 1, column A corresponds to 0, 0.
row = int(seat[:-1]) - 1   # raises ValueError if the row isn't a number
col = ord(seat[-1:].upper()) - ord('A')
seat_map[row][col] = seat  # raises IndexError if seat is out of bounds
```

Comment: OK,thanks for your stylistic comments, appreciated. Now the crucks of the question: is there anything which could be improved? how about feedback on writing the same answer without resorting to regular expression matching?

Comment: The easier your code is to read, the more substantive feedback you'll get on code review; I focused on the commenting style first because it was distracting to the point that I was hindered from reading the code to be able to suggest improvements.  :)  I'll do a quick edit to add a non-regexy way to parse seats though.

Comment: Using `ord(seat[-1].upper()) - ord('A')`, how do you suggest to handle *no column capital i*?

Comment: I didn't even notice the omission of I.  Assuming that wasn't a typo, I'd just do `if col >= 8: col -= 1 # column I(8) doesn't exist` to handle the "skipped" column.

Answer (score 1):

## `;`

why all the `;`. Python is not JS. They don't do any harm to the program, but they are unnecessary and hamper the readability

## 1 letter variable names

I try to avoid those as much as possible, unless they are the standard jargon in for example mathematical formula's, `i` as counter or `x` and `y` as coordinate

## Comments

As already noted in the other answers. Comments should explain why you did something. What you do should be clear from the code, variable names, .... They should explain the edge cases, limitations, why you do the -1 to get to 0-based indexing.

Part of this can be helped by splitting the code into smaller functions with their doctstring

## reassigning variable names

Like you do in `S = S.split(' ');` is a practice that leads to simple errors. Better to give the parsed product another name

## split the work in functions

Your `Solution` method does a lot of work. It 
- translates the input string
- assembles the plane
- iterates over the rows
- asks `sliceMatrix` the number of free clusters
- sums the number for all rows

Better would be to split this into more functions

## translating the input string

A simple method that translates the coordinates to row and column indices can be as simple as:

```
def translate_seats(input_string):
    """
    Translates the input string to 0-indexed seat, row, column tuples

    skips the row "I". 
    case insensitive

    example: 
    "1A 1B 1F 2A 2B 2C 2D 3A 3C 3D 4A 4B 4E 5A 6K"
    --> [
            ("1A", 0, 0),
            ("1B", 0, 1),
            ("1F", 0, 5),
            ("2A", 1, 0),
            ("2B", 1, 1),
            ("2C", 1, 2),
            ("2D", 1, 3),
            ("3A", 2, 0),
            ("3C", 2, 2),
            ("3D", 2, 3),
            ("4A", 3, 0),
            ("4B", 3, 1),
            ("4E", 3, 4),
            ("5A", 4, 0),
            ('6K', 5, 9),
        ]
    """
    if not input_string:
        return
    COLUMNS = {
        "a": 0,
        "b": 1,
        "c": 2,
        "d": 3,
        "e": 4,
        "f": 5,
        "g": 6,
        "h": 7,
        "j": 8,
        "k": 9,
    }
    for seat in input_string.split(" "):
        row = int(seat[:-1]) - 1
        column = COLUMNS[seat[-1].lower()]
        yield seat, row, column
```

The docstring immediately makes clear what this method does, and it being separate enables easy testing

## 'Building' the plane

Instead of 0 as placeholder for an empty seat, I've use `None`, since I think this better describes the chair being empty

```
def assemble_plane(rows, seats, columns=10):
    """
    < docstring >
    """
    plane = [
        [None] * columns
        for _ in range(rows)
    ]
    for seat, row, column in translate_seats(seats):
        plane[row][column] = seat
    return plane
```

> ```
> rows = 7
> seats = "1A 1B 1F 2A 2B 2C 2D 3A 3C 3D 4A 4B 4E 5A"
> assemble_plane(rows, seats, columns=10)
> ```

```
[['1A', '1B', None, None, None, '1F', None, None, None, None],
 ['2A', '2B', '2C', '2D', None, None, None, None, None, None],
 ['3A', None, '3C', '3D', None, None, None, None, None, None],
 ['4A', '4B', None, None, '4E', None, None, None, None, None],
 ['5A', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
 [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
 [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]]
```

I've added `columns` as an optional argument, should you ever wish wider or narrower planes.

In the inner loop, `[None] * columns` works since a new list is generated for each row, but the outer loop needs the `for _ in range(rows)` instead of `* rows`

## `sliceMatrix`

Has a number of things wrong. `C` and `i` are not used. It prints and calculates. If you want to see what happens, you either use a debugger, or use the logging module.

Instead of counting the number of `0`s, you can also use the `any()` builtin if you used a `False`y placeholder for empty seats to test whether any of the seats is occupied.

Instead of the `for`-loop, I would make this an explicit `while`-loop with your own indexer (`location`)

I changed the magic number 4 you had in your method to an optional argument.

```
import logging
def clusters_in_row(row, cluster_length=4):
    """
    < docstring >
    """
    counter = 0
    location = 0

    while location < len(row) - cluster_length + 1:
        # no need to check the last 3 seats for a cluster of 4
        my_slice = row[location : location + cluster_length]
        if any(my_slice): # an occupied seat, move on
            location += 1
            continue
        counter += 1
        logging.debug(f"empty cluster found starting on {location}")
        location += cluster_length
    return counter
```

Yet again, this is a small function whose function is clear, and can be independently tested

## putting it together

```
def solution(rows: int, seats: str):
    columns = 10 # plane is 10 seats wide
    cluster_length = 4
    plane = assemble_plane(rows, seats, columns=columns)
    total = 0

    for i, row in enumerate(plane, 1):
        empty_clusters = clusters_in_row(row, cluster_length=cluster_length)
        logging.debug(f"row {i} has {empty_clusters} empty clusters")
        total += empty_clusters
    return total
```

If you don't need the extra debug logging, you can even use the builtin `sum`

```
def solution(rows: int, seats: str):
    columns = 10  # plane is 10 seats wide
    cluster_length = 4
    plane = assemble_plane(rows, seats, columns=columns)
    total = 0

    return sum(
        clusters_in_row(row, cluster_length=cluster_length) for row in plane
    )
```

Comment: Many thanks for everyone's valuable feedback.
I come from a C/C++/Assembly background, writing real-time code for safety-critical applications; hence the comment describing what each line does: you'd get slaughtered by the reviewers in these domains if your code is documented this way, however mundane the comments are.
Still; this is really useful feedback for me to take on my journey towards acquiring Python as a dev tool.